# Need regex to extract fields from string

Tags: regex

I need to extract the title, location, and price from a string like this:

```
10' Starcraft pop up camper (Newport) $5500
```

It should be obvious which are which.

However, there are also cases like this:

```
10' (approx.) Starcraft pop up camper (Drigg's Town, PA) $5500
```

_

When I use a simple regex, I can match the first string correctly, but not the second:

```
^(?<title>.+?) \((?<area>.+?)\) \$(?<price>[\d]+)$
```

_

I'm pretty sure lookaheads/backreferences can handle this, but I don't know how. Can someone help me out with some explanation? (And maybe references to an easy to read article on the subject.)

Comment: No. It doesn't have anything to do with lookaround and backreference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only 2 examples, the best I can suggest is to change the lazy quantifier to greedy quantifier for `title` capturing group:

```
^(?<title>.+) \((?<area>.+?)\) \$(?<price>[\d]+)$
           ^^
          Here
```

Effectively, the pattern in `area` capturing group will now capture the text **inside the last brackets** `()` (providing that it is followed by text that can be matched by `price` capturing group).

The greedy quantifier in `title` consumes as much text as possible, and force the `area` capturing group to take the furthest possible match.

---

Another way is to make sure the sub-pattern in `area` capturing group does not contain `()`:

```
^(?<title>.+) \((?<area>[^()]+)\) \$(?<price>[\d]+)$
           ^^           ^^^^^^
          Here           Here
```

I also remove the lazy quantifier, since it is redundant. There is only one way to match bracket `()` characters, which is before and after the text captured by `area` capturing group.

---

The 2 solutions above assume that `area` will never contain bracket `()` characters. The pattern is going to be slightly more complicated if you want to allow that.